# _tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage1" doesn't exist, I am new to python

Tags: python, image, tkinter

I need help with creating a button with an image, the creation of the image seems to not be a problem as when I hover over the file location of the image, the image pops up. However, the error image "pyimage1" doesn't exist shows up as seen in the screenshots. This is for a cookie clicker type game for a school project and I am very knew to Python (3 days of learning so far).

```
from tkinter import *

gui = Tk()
clicks = 0


class Game():
multiplier = 0

global upgrades
upgrades = ["2", "4", "6", "8", "10", "20"], ["Upgrade 1", "Upgrade 2", "Upgrade 3", "Upgrade 4", "Upgrade 5", "Maxed"]

def setMultiplier(x):
    multiplier = x
    print(multiplier)

def clickcmd(multiplier):
    global clicks
    clicks += 1 * (multiplier)
    return clicks

def up1cmd(x):
    setMultiplier(upgrades[0][x])

# x = Which upgrade was bought, returns upgrade[x]
def getUpgrade(x):
    return upgrades[0, x], upgrades[1, x]
```

`

```
from tkinter import *
from Game import Game

gui = Tk()
gui.title("Clicking Mania")
gui.geometry("600x600")


# Inside GUI title
title = Label(gui, text="Clicking Mania")
title.pack()
title.grid_location(3, 2)


# Images
image = PhotoImage(file='../GameImages/DPic.png')
imagelabel = Label(image=image)
imageshop = PhotoImage(file='../GameImages/upgrade.png')
imageupgrade = Label(image=imageshop)


# Buttons
pickaxebutton = Button(gui, image=image, command=Game.clickcmd(1), borderwidth=0)
pickaxebutton.pack(pady=100)
upgradebutton = Button(gui, image=imageshop, borderwidth=0)


# change image
up1button = Button(gui, image=image, command=Game.up1cmd(), borderwidth=0)

balance = Label(gui, text="Balance: ", padx=20, pady=10)
balance.pack()

gui.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please [edit]  your question to include the code and error message as text. Images of code are useless.

Comment: Is that better?

Comment: Better, but you should do some research first. If you search for that exact error message you'll see several similar questions, some with answers.

Answer (score -1):

Hard to tell with just seeing a couple lines of your code, but most likely the path to the image is wrong. Try using the OS library to print out your current path.

`import os
os.getcwd()`

Then from there you can figure out what path you need to give. Or you can give an absolute path to see if that is the issue or not.

Comment: The OP would get a completely different error message if they had the path wrong.